# Google Maps, create map using place_id

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Is it possible to, using Google API's, create a map for the website that looks exactly like this one:

https://www.google.pl/maps/place/Googleplex/@37.422,-122.0840835,19z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x808fba02425dad8f:0x6c296c66619367e0

So what I want is to pass the place Id to the API to get a place like this Googleplex place, and I want the marker to be on it and the place name to be red.

I'm using api v3, and I would like to directly pass to it the id of the place not to use search like mentioned here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_searches

I also don't want to embed a pregenerated one, as the area map needs to cover is dynamic to page width and height.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [PlacesService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlacesService) and the `getDetails()` method.

```
function initialize() {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433, 151.1956316),
        zoom: 15
    });

    var request = {
        placeId: 'ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4'
    };

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    service.getDetails(request, function (place, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: place.geometry.location
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                infowindow.setContent(place.name);
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            });
        }
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-details

Comment: That is close, but still I would like to achive what is on the map I linked, so the place name to be red and blue when hovered.

Comment: There is no option to do that with the API. Have a look at [MarkerWithLabel](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.8/docs/examples.html) library.

Answer (score 0):

The function has 3 inputs that you should have stored in your code.
(Here you can find the place_id: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder)
You should change the map ID (or pass it as input).

```
function initMap(place_id, lat, lng){
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('js-concrete_map'), {
        center: {lat: lat, lng: lng},
        zoom: 15
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    service.getDetails({
        placeId: place_id
    }, function(place, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: place.geometry.location
          });
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(place.name);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
          });
        }
    });
}
```